# Error when deploying Regain for tomcat server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have been working with this for weeks now and cannot find a way to fix this. When I deply regain.war for my server, I get the following error:

```
type Exception report
message /index.jsp (line: 2, column: 0) null

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 2, column: 0) null
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:275)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:91)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:335)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:368)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:471)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1435)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.30 logs.
```

Here is the code in index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" errorPage="errorpage.jsp" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="searchinput.jsp" %>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to finally just install the local desktop version of regain on my server and then proxy its webpages through a php script. Dirty, but it works.